# Obtaining the Qt 4.8 SDK

Tags: qt, sdk, qt4.8

I haven't used Qt on Windows in a while. I know that now we're supposed to download the open source version from the Qt Project website.

But the page at http://qt-project.org/downloads has separate links to installers for Qt libraries and Qt Creator. I remember being able to just download the full SDK and get started, but now I have t separately install MinGW, the libraries and Qt Creator.

Can I still get the libraries and Qt Creator in a single bundle, and if yes, where should I look?

Comment: Turunen Tuukka of digia says: "The upcoming Qt 5 beta 2 will include Creator and can thus be considered an SDK, although not an online one. Going forward we plan to make it online SDK and enable also Qt 4.8 in it so that there is again SDK for LGPL users through the Qt Project." http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2012/11/08/qt-creator-2-6-0-released/#comment-59555

Comment: Nice to hear that! I was afraid that they're going to give the comlete SDK to the commercial version users only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just downloaded Qt SDK from http://download.cnet.com/Qt-SDK/3000-2069_4-75305206.html

It seems to be working, although windows says the installer is unsigned.

Answer (score 1):

Digia distributes the SDK now. Not sure if it's still free. http://qt.digia.com/Product/Qt-SDK/

Comment: But this only provides a link to a 30-day free evaluation version for those who want to buy the commercial version, while I want the normal free SDK that can be used to develop open source applications.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Guess they have to make their money somehow... I use Creator and Qt as separate downloads anyway, so I don't miss it. I like having fine control over which version of Qt I'm compiling with.

Answer (score 0):

[There is a installation guide](http://tudat.tudelft.nl/projects/tudat/wiki/Installation_Guide) plus full SDK (1.2.1), both LINUX/WINDOWS including supplemental files. No non-functional Windows-MinGW installation is required here.