# Link to Qt SDK?

Tags: qt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Obtaining the Qt 4.8 SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13426144/obtaining-the-qt-4-8-sdk)

I need to reinstall Qt SDK, and I can't find a download link anywhere. I'm talking about the one that installs in "C:\QtSDK", and comes with a package manager, "Maintain Qt SDK" and "Update Qt SDK".

All the links seem to be dead, and at http://qt-project.org/downloads only the libraries and Qt Creator are offered, but as separate downloads, and there is no link to QtSDK.

Is it no longer available?